# Can't delete dynamic object created in WxApp from OnExit()

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I'm trying to understand how a WxWidgets (3.0.1) app should be designed, but I'm missing something as what I'm trying doesn't work.

At basic level, I have my WxApp, it creates a WxFrame, it gets displayed and all works fine.
Then I decided to add in a logger object....

I made the object a member of my WxApp:

```
class IniLogWx : public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool            OnInit( );  
        virtual int             OnExit( );  

    private:
        cLogStore *             cl_LogStore;
};
```

And initialised it in WxApp::OnInit()

```
bool IniLogWx::OnInit( )
{
    MainFrame * frame = new MainFrame(_("Log Demo"), wxPoint(250, 250), wxSize(450, 340));
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);

    // Create Logger Class
    cLogStore * cl_LogStore = new cLogStore( );

    return true;
}
```

When the application is closed (closing the MainFrame) WxApp::OnExit() fires, and I *thought* I'd be able to clean up my memory here

```
int IniLogWx::OnExit( )
{
    delete cl_LogStore; // Unhandled Exception here due to invalid pointer

    return wxApp::OnExit();
}
```

However, it would appear that the pointer is no longer valid so I cannot use it to delete my assigned memory.

The manual says "OnExit is called after destroying all application windows and controls, but before wxWidgets cleanup." so I figured my own additional attributes would still be available to me.

Is this not the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating a local variable that happens to match the name you used in your class.

```
// Create Logger Class
cLogStore * cl_LogStore = new cLogStore( );
```

The `cl_LogStore` here is not the same as the member variable `cl_LogStore`.  It is a local variable.  Thus not only did you call `delete` on an invalid pointer value, you have a memory leak.

Comment: I don't believe I missed that! That is indeed where I was going wrong. Many thanks.